# checking which decimal is bigger django

Tags: python, django

Im having problem with one line of code... Im trying to check which decimal is greater, i checked few answers from stackoverflow and they didnt work (probably cuz they were from 7 years ago :P) anyways here is my view:

```
    auction = all_auctions.objects.get(id= my_id)
    comment_num = auction.comments.all().count()
    all_comments = auction.comments.all()
    context = {
        "auction": auction,
        "bid_auction": auction.bid.all(),
        "comment_num": comment_num,
        "all_comments": all_comments
    }
    if request.method == "POST" and "bid" in request.POST:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            highest_bid = request.POST["bid"]
            if not Decimal(highest_bid) <= Decimal(int(auction.bid.all().reverse()[0])):
                all_bid = bids.objects.create(bid = highest_bid)
                auction.bid.add(all_bid)
    if request.method == "POST" and "watch"in request.POST:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if auction not in request.user.watchlist.all():
                request.user.watchlist.add(auction)
            else:
                request.user.watchlist.remove(auction)
    if request.method == "POST" and "comment" in request.POST:
        comment = request.POST["comment"]
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            comment_now = comments.objects.create(comment = comment)
            auction.comments.add(comment_now)
    return render(request, "auctions/dynamic_auction.html", context)
```

and there is the problematic line:

```
if not Decimal(highest_bid) <= Decimal(int(auction.bid.all().reverse()[0])):
```

in models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(blank=False)
class bids(models.Model):
    bid = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 100000)
class all_auctions(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length= 14, default = "none")
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 14)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    photo_url = models.CharField(max_length= 500000)
    bid = models.ManyToManyField(bids, blank = True, related_name = "bid_auction")
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(comments, blank = True, related_name = "comments")
class User(AbstractUser):
    created =  models.ManyToManyField(all_auctions, blank = True, related_name = "created")
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(all_auctions, blank = True, related_name = "watchlist")
    user_bid = models.ManyToManyField(bids, blank = True, related_name = "user_bid")
```

and in the template where i can place bids and view them:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<div>
    <h2>{{auction.title}}</h2>
    <div style = "width: 1400px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;" class = auction_class>
        <img src="{{auction.photo_url}}" alt="no image">
        <div>
            {{auction.description}}
            <p></p>
            {% for bid in bid_auction %}
                {% if forloop.last %}
                    bid:{{bid.bid}}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <p></p>
            {{auction.category}}
            <p></p>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <form method = "POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name = "watch" value="Add to watchlist">
                </form>
                <form  method = "POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                    <div>
                      <input style = "margin:10px;" class="form-control" name = "bid" type="text" placeholder= "Bid...">
                      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Place Bid">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form  method = "POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                    <div>
                        <input style = "margin:10px;" class="form-control" name = "comment" type="text" placeholder= "Comment...">
                    </div>
                </form>

            {% endif %}
            <p></p>
            comments:
            <p></p>
            {% if comment_num == 0 %}
                no comments
            {% endif %}
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            {% for com in all_comments %}
                  {{ com.comment }}
                  <p></p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and yes i made it so the last object of the bids queryset is shown, i have no idea how to show the biggest one, so also i would appreciate help with that . thanks :D

Comment: What do you mean by "problematic"? Does it produce an error? Does it have an unexpected result?

Comment: For the "last" object you can use `[-1]` instead of `reverse()[0]`.

Comment: nope i cant use [-1] i tried it and by problematic i mean this error:```int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'bids'```

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't worked with django alot but since you want to compare decimals you could technically create a class which inherits the class `Decimal()`  and then return a float and compare that float. Although I think this won't work (I haven't tried it because I don't like django in particular) but this could be a possibility.

EDIT:
Use a function to return a float from the class.

Example Code:

```
class DecimalNumber(Decimal):
    def __init__(self, value, par2...):
        self.value = value
        ...
    def return_float(self):
        float = self.value
        return float
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this:

```
if not Decimal(highest_bid) <= Decimal(int(auction.bid.all().reverse()[0].bid)):
```

should work (note `.bid` in the end).

And why you can't use `[-1]`?

Comment: maybe: if not Decimal(highest_bid) <= auction.bid.all().reverse()[0].bid:

Comment: nope still doesnt work, i dont get an error but now just nothing happens

Comment: @Tryjis saying that is not the way to get help out here. If you don't have an error anymore, that probably is progress. And "nothing happens" means you don't really know what is going on and what is happening. If there is another issue, you should try resolving it yourself. You can try posting another question if you are stuck.